# Return internal class calling object function

Tags: android, object, architecture, kotlin, internal

I'm testing with Kotlin and I'm writing a small library to be imported and used by a test App project.

In the library project I marked my classes as `internal` because I don't want them to be visible for the App project, but I would like to have a single entry point for the library, and for that I am using a Kotlin `object` like shown below

```
LIBRARY

object Library {
   fun getComponent() = AwesomeComponent()
}

internal class AwesomeComponent() {
   // some implementation
}


TEST APP

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
      val component = Library.getComponent()
   }
}
```

The problem is that this doesn't compile because the function in the Library `object` returns an `internal` type and therefore need to be marked as internal as well, but doing so would hide the function from the TestApp.

Another option would be to not have the `internal` modifier at all so the TestApp can see the Library method, but then it can also see the classes inside the Library project

Is there an easy solution that I am overlooking here or does it need to go through re-planning of packages and structure of the Library project? (not sure how to do it in that case)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to publish some sort of public API for the app module to be able to use the component that the `getComponent()` method returns. If you want to publish minimal information about your library, you can have it return an interface that contains only the publicly available method calls to the library, and make your class implement that interface:

```
object Library {
    fun getComponent(): IAwesomeComponent = AwesomeComponent()
}

interface IAwesomeComponent {
     // methods you want to call on the component in the app module
}

internal class AwesomeComponent(): IAwesomeComponent {
    // implementations of the interface methods
}
```

Comment: I'd say that the API should normally have the "better" names: `interface AwesomeComponent` and `internal class AwesomeComponentImpl(): AwesomeComponent`.

Comment: Good point - I just wanted to explain it with the least change to the original code.